# Internet Explorer Doesn't Support JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

I am recently reading about Node.js and got an interesting statement about JavaScript and Internet Explorer:

> Internet Explorer doesn’t actually support JavaScript or ECMAScript; it supports a language variety called JScript. In recent years, JScript has fully supported the ECMAScript 3 standard and has some ECMAScript 5 support. However, JScript also implements proprietary extensions in the same way that Mozilla JavaScript does and has features that ECMAScript does not.
>
> Source: http://chimera.labs.oreilly.com/books/1234000001808/ch01.html#chap2_id35941400

Frankly speaking I am totally unable to understand the above statement. I know Microsoft has its own `VBScript` and it allowed JavaScript in IE that is why JS is more popular than any other scripting language. Is this statement true? If yes then the scripting engine of IE does the translations of native JavaScript to JScript or what is the other case?

Comment: [**JScript**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JScript) is basically JavaScript, the reason Microsoft had to use another name was trademark issues, not because it was any different.

Comment: This is like how we have html standards, and each browser has its own interpretation of how to render html.  Some features may be unsupported or beyond the specs, but it still ends up being a browser rendering html.

Comment: *"Internet Explorer doesn’t actually support JavaScript or ECMAScript; it supports... Jscript. In recent years, JScript has fully supported the ECMAScript 3 standard"* So they don't support ECMAScript, but they do fully support it. Alrighty then.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ECMAScript is the official standard, JavaScript and JScript are implementations of that standard. Just like CPython and Jython are implementations of Python.

As so often if it's about browsers, they both don't necessarily fully support the standard or provide additional, non-standard features, partly because they started evolving when an official standard didn't exist yet.

From [Wikipedia about JScript](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JScript):

> [Microsoft] did not want to deal with Sun about the trademark issue, and so they called their implementation JScript. A lot of people think that JScript and JavaScript are different but similar languages. That's not the case. They are just different names for the same language, and the reason the names are different was to get around trademark issues

From the [Microsoft documentation about JScript](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hbxc2t98%28v=vs.85%29.aspx):

> JScript is the Microsoft implementation of the ECMA 262 language specification (ECMAScript Edition 3). With only a few minor exceptions (to maintain backwards compatibility), JScript is a full implementation of the ECMA standard.

Comment: So the statement given in the, I have referred is wrong? Because If I take the definition you have mentioned, (which seems correct), then that one is totally wrong

Comment: Well, the first sentence seems a bit strange. You cannot say that the browser doesn't support ECMAScript and in the next sentence say it uses something that is compatible to ECMAScript. But the rest seems to be correct: JScript is compatible with ES3 but also has non-standard features. You could say the same about Firefox: Firefox does not support JScript, it uses JavaScript. It's compatible to ES3 but also has non-standard features. What is correct is that IE does not support JavaScript ;)

Comment: @AwaisQarni: I'd say the statement *"[…] doesn’t actually support JavaScript or ECMAScript […]"* is very shady at best. If we bring in DOM scripting it is another cake.

Comment: @FelixKling yes agree. If we remove the first statement then else seems understandable because of your well explanation. +1 for that :-)

Comment: Mmmm... DOM scripting cake.

Comment: @AwaisQarni: Moist, chocolaty DOM scripting [cake](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22679460/internet-explorer-doesnt-support-javascript/22679663?noredirect=1#comment34550908_22679663). I love it.

Answer (score 1):

well, this mainly depends on the version of IE you are using, as you havent mentioned that no one can say that for sure

Answer (score 1):

I think it is not like that instead Microsoft gives you an option to enable Javascript on your  IE like this:

- Pull down your TOOLS menu
- Select Internet Options...
- Click the Security tab on the top of the resulting window
- Click the Custom Level button
- Scroll the list down to the entry for Active Scripting
- Check the Enable radio button.
- Click OK in all dialogs.

Also [Jscript](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JScript) is same as Javascript

> JScript is Microsoft's dialect of the ECMAScript standard[2] that is
> used in Microsoft's Internet Explorer.
>
> JScript is implemented as a
> Active Scripting engine. This means that it can be "plugged in" to OLE
> Automation applications that support Active Scripting, such as
> Internet Explorer, Active Server Pages, and Windows Script Host.[3] It
> also means such applications can use multiple Active Scripting
> languages (e.g., JScript, VBScript, PerlScript, etc.).